# Speed up iteration for large dataset in python

Tags: python, performance, csv, iteration

I'm trying to parse data into a csv prior to a bulk transaction into Neo4j.  I'm using vast amounts of data in the relationships and wondered if anyone could help in speeding up the transactions below.  It's genomic data, with 2,000 samples, each with up to 3.5m variants per chromosome probably equating to about 40m variants, up to two rows per sample, so ~120,000,000,000 rows in total.  Currently it's taking me about 20 minutes per sample.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve this:

```
import sys
import time
import datetime
import numpy as np
import allel
import zarr
import numcodecs
import os
import pandas
import csv
import math
import dask.array as da
vcf_directory = '/media/user/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/uk_alspac/'
zarr_path = vcf_directory + 'chroms.zarr'
callset = zarr.open_group(zarr_path, mode='r')
samples_fn = '/media/user/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/uk_alspac/phenotype_data/EGAZ00001016605_UK10K_ALSPAC_Phenotype_Data_August_2013_1867samples.txt'
panel = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(samples_fn, sep='\t')
chrom_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,'X']
i = 0
j = 0
seq_tech = 'Illumina HiSeq 2000 (ILLUMINA)'
with open('/media/user/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/uk_alspac/Import_files/sample_variants.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    filewriter.writerow([':START_ID(Sample)','type', 'hapA', 'hapB','genotype', 'seqtech', 'read_depth', 'phase_set','GP0','GP1','GP2','PL0','PL1','PL2', ':END_ID(Variant)'])
    for chrom in chrom_list:
        print(chrom)
        datetime_object = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(datetime_object) 
        sampledata = callset[chrom]['samples']
        samples = list(sampledata)
        variants = allel.VariantChunkedTable(callset[chrom]['variants'], names=['AC','AF_AFR', 'AF_AMR', 'AF_ASN', 'AF_EUR', 'AF_MAX', 'CGT', 'CLR', 'CSQ', 'DP', 'DP4', 'ESP_MAF', 'FILTER_LowQual', 'FILTER_MinHWE', 'FILTER_MinVQSLOD', 'FILTER_PASS', 'HWE', 'ICF', 'ID', 'IS', 'PC2', 'PCHI2', 'POS', 'PR', 'QCHI2', 'QUAL', 'REF', 'ALT', 'INDEL', 'SHAPEIT', 'SNP_ID', 'TYPE', 'UGT', 'VQSLOD', 'dbSNPmismatch', 'is_snp', 'numalt', 'svlen'], index='POS')
        pos = variants['POS'][:]
        SNPid = variants['ID'][:]
        ref = variants['REF'][:]
        alt = variants['ALT'][:]
        dp = variants['DP'][:]
        ac = variants['AC'][:]
        vartype = variants['TYPE'][:]
        svlen = variants['svlen'][:]
        qual = variants['QUAL'][:]
        vq = variants['VQSLOD'][:]
        numalt = variants['numalt'][:]
        csq = variants['CSQ'][:]
        vcfv = 'VCFv4.1'
        refv = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/GCF_000001405.13/'
        calldata = callset[chrom]['calldata']
        dpz = calldata['DP']
        psz = calldata['PS']
        plz = calldata['PL']
        gpz = calldata['GP']
        gtz = calldata['GT']
        i = 0
        j = 0
        seq_tech = 'Illumina HiSeq 2000 (ILLUMINA)'
        for i in range(50):
            print("Chrom " + str(chrom) + "sample" + str(i))
            print(datetime_object)
            gt = gtz[:,i].tolist()
            hap1, hap2 = zip(*gt)
            dp = dpz[:, i]
            ps = psz[:, i]
            pl = plz[:, i]
            gp = gpz[:, i]
            subject = samples[i]
            for j in range(len(pos)): 
                h1 = int(hap1[j])
                h2 = int(hap2[j])
                read_depth = int(dp[j])
                ps1 = int(ps[j])
                PL0 = int(pl[j][0])
                PL1 = int(pl[j][1])
                PL2 = int(pl[j][2])        
                GP0 = float(gp[j][0])
                GP1 = float(gp[j][1])
                GP2 = float(gp[j][2])

                if h1 == 0 and h2 == 0:
                    filewriter.writerow([subject,"Homozygous",h1 ,h2, str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + ref[j]])
                elif h1 == 0 and h2 > 0:  
                    filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype A",h1 ,'', str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + ref[j]])
                    filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype B",'',h2, str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + alt[j][h2-1]])
                elif h1 > 0 and h2 == 0:
                    filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype A",h1, '', str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + alt[j][h1-1]])
                    filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype B",'' ,h2, str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + ref[j]])
                elif h1 == h2 and h1 > 0:
                    filewriter.writerow([subject,"Homozygous",h1, h2, str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + alt[j][h1-1]])     
                else:
                    filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype A",h1,'', str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + alt[j][h1-1]])
                    filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype B",'',h2, str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + alt[j][h2-1]])
```

It was all done a bit ad-hoc and I'm still new to python, so any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Ludisposed.  Can you tell me what difference it will be making here?  The results seem to come out as anticipated and I'm hesitant to stop the loop as I'll have to start over again.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry @Ludisposed that was just a formatting error when writing the question.  I've corrected it now.  It's running at the moment, I just wondered if there was any way to speed up the loop.